# How does passing an object to MultipartFormDataContent implicitly call the Add method?

Tags: c#, constructor

I don't really understand this, take this code:

```
var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { content, "fileData", fileName }
};
```

It seems unclear what this is doing, so if I add another parameter as such:

```
var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { content, "fileData", fileName, "<new_param>" }
};
```

It says:

*Error  CS1501  No overload for method 'Add' takes 4 arguments*

So clearly, this is internally calling the `Add` method.

I look in the source code (https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/MultipartFormDataContent.cs) and there isn't anything special I can see here that would facilitate this.

So my question is.... How are we calling `Add` implicitly when we use `new` on `MultipartFormDataContent`?

Comment: [Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers). Note that it's a *language* feature, not something specific to `MultipartFormDataContent` as such (other than it matching the right pattern to take advantage of it)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If you make an answer I will mark it correct.